# Selecting the first item of an ARRAY with PostgreSQL/SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Trying to move some queries I run daily into an automated script.  I have one in Postgres like the below:

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_array(col1, "|")[1] AS item, COUNT(*) AS itemcount FROM Tabel1 GROUP BY item ORDER BY itemcount
```

In SqlAlchemy I have this:

```
session.query((func.regexp_split_to_array(model.table1.col1, "|")[1]).label("item"), func.count().label("itemcount")).group_by("item").order_by("itemcount")
```

Python can't "get_item" since it's not actually a collection.  I've looked through the docs and can't seem to find something that would let me do this without running raw SQL using execute (which I can do and works, but was looking for a solution for next time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLAlchemy does support indexing with `[...]`. If you declare a type of a column that you have to be of type `postgresql.ARRAY`, then it works:

```
table2 = Table("table2", meta, Column("col1", postgresql.ARRAY(String)))
q = session.query(table2.c.col1[1])
print(q.statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
# SELECT table2.col1[%(col1_1)s] AS anon_1 
# FROM table2
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is that SQLAlchemy does not know that `func.regexp_split_to_array(...)` returns an array, since `func.foo` produces a generic function for convenience. To make it work, we need to make sure SQLAlchemy knows the return type of the function, by specifying the `type_` parameter:

```
q = session.query(func.regexp_split_to_array(table1.c.col1, "|", type_=postgresql.ARRAY(String))[1].label("item"))
print(q.statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
# SELECT (regexp_split_to_array(table1.col1, %(regexp_split_to_array_1)s))[%(regexp_split_to_array_2)s] AS item 
# FROM table1
```

Comment: Requires sqlalchemy.types for String (which I didn't have imported for reasons that not good), but otherwise works like a charm.  Thanks!